# Should it read "dot" when there is a period in the sentence in talkback

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I am testing accessibility in Android app with talkback. It reads out 'dot' when there is a period in the sentence. Is this the correct way of doing accessibility? To be specific, it happens only after a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is fine, and Talkback users will probably be used to it. As a developer, you should NOT attempt to control this yourself.

When reading text containing links, Talkback will pause on links to give the user the opportunity to activate the link if they choose. The behaviour takes the sentence structure into account. For example:

- When reading paragraphs without any links, there will be pauses between sentences, but the period punctuation marks are not announced.
- When there's a link in the middle of a sentence, Talkback breaks the sentence into parts.

  1. It reads all the words before the link, then pauses.
  2. When the user swipes to continue, the link text is announced (together with the fact that it is a link). Speech then pauses, and the user can activate the link.
  3. On the next swipe, Talkback reads the remainder of the sentence or paragraph. The period is not announced.
- When the link is at the end of a sentence, we have a special variation. After the link, the period is the *only thing which remains at the end of the sentence*.  I believe the text-to-speech engine intentionally announces the period, to be clear that the sentence is finished.

This behaviour is generally helpful, and many other screen readers do something similar.  The exact behaviour varies depending on which text-to-speech engine is used, and different rules will be used for each language or region. With a British voice we hear "full stop", for instance.  Users can change the verbosity settings of some screen readers too.